# From MinGW static library (.a) to Visual Studio static library (.lib)

Tags: visual-studio, static, mingw

I'm trying to use [xlsLib](http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/) for creating Excel spreadsheets from a C++ application.

The trouble is that compiling xlsLib, I give a .a file (a GCC static library, generated by MinGW). But, my application depends on another API (`PhysX`) that only compiles with Visual Studio.

Thus: is it possible to transform the GCC static library (`xlslib.a`) to a Visual Studio static library file (`xlslib.lib`)?

Answer (score 38):

The archives of static libraries generated with MinGW are generally compatible with Visual C++ compiler/linker. So, you should be able to use them directly by adding `.a` files to linker input in your project properties in Visual Studio:

1. Go to project `Properties` (Alt-F7).
2. On the left box, open `Configuration Properties->Linker->Input`
3. Add list of all `.a` archives you need to use
4. You may need to add also MinGW's `libgcc.a` library

Also, there may occur problems regarding mixed C run-time libraries `properties of C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library`, but this depends on your build configuration you use with MinGW. Sometimes it is necessary to link against `libmsvcrt.a` from MinGW but in many (if not most) cases it causes problems.

Finally, this mixed MinGW and Visual C++ linking generally works but for C modules and it does not work for C++, as far as I know.

Comment: but using .a causes my .exe to not be able to debug "Debugging information can not be found".

Comment: @onmyway133 check whether a debugging symbols is still present. You can use e.g. `nm --debug-syms`, and if the binary stripped, it says «no symbols».

Comment: adding libgcc.a was important for me

Comment: You say I can generate static library using `MinGW64` and use it as a resource in an MSVC project?

Answer (score 4):

> but using .a causes my .exe to not be able to debug "Debugging information can not be found". –  entropy May 22 at 12:27

that's because the .a library does not include the debug info necessary for debugging. you need to tell the compiler to add debug info when in compilation if you want to debug it. for mingw, you need to add "`-g`" to CFLAGS when you run "`make`", like "`make CFLAGS="-g"`"

Answer (score 0):

Here are two resources I have found useful:

[snip, wrong link]

http://old.nabble.com/using-VC%2B%2B-.lib-with-mingw-td23151303.html

Edit. I can't find the link I was looking for. In the meanwhile, check this one out: http://www.willus.com/mingw/yongweiwu_stdcall.html

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, they are the same thing. Visual Studio's `.lib` files are also `ar` archives containing object files. Did you try just renaming the file? :)

Comment: No, it's not that simple, the format of the actual archive is slightly different.

Comment: I believe there is also a tool lib.exe that comes with visual studio. Using a .def file you can convert the .a to .lib.