# How do you compile a PHP extension on windows with cygwin/mingw?

Tags: php, cygwin, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to build the [RabbitMQ PHP wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/php-rabbit/) and the [AMPQ PHP wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/php-amqp/) on Windows (64) using Cygwin.
I have successfully built the underlying C library (librabbitmq.dll) but I am stuck at the 'phpize' step:

`phpize && ./configure --with-rabbit && make && sudo make install`

If I understand correctly, there is no 'phpize' on windows, so how do I build my PHP wrapper?

Note that I'm totally new to building PHP extensions (be it on linux or windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally not supported.  PHP is designed to be compiled with GNUmake on UNIX/POSIX systems and Visual C++ on Windows systems.

Your only option, really, is to download [Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) (2010 is not certified to work at present, to my knowledge).

You can then link to dlls compiled using mingw in your own custom extension.  Try this Stack Overflow guide: [From MinGW static library (.a) to Visual Studio static library (.lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib).

Comment: OK, it's not as bad as I feared then. I'll try this right now.

Comment: This may have improved in more recent versions of PHP. I know that people like @PierreJoye are working on making PHP a first class citizen on Windows. Unfortunately I seldom use PHP these days so I am unsure what the current situation is...

Comment: I can confirm, sadly, that as of February 2012, this is still very much an issue.  If in doubt, just pick your random PHP extension and attempt compiling in 2010.