# Has anyone compiled a rabbitmq/amqp library for php 5.2.x on windows x64

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-extension

I'm trying to publish messages to RabbitMQ from a php (5.2.x) script on my windows X64 dev machine.

The problem is that I didn't find any dll extension for php. My collegue is actually trying to build it (cf. [How do you compile a PHP extension on windows with cygwin/mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711327/how-do-you-compile-a-php-extension-on-windows-with-cygwin-mingw)), but without success :(.

Does anyone know where I can find a valid/working RabbitMQ dll extension for php (5.2.x)? Or if someone has the experience to do it correctly and quickly it would certainly be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [php-amqplib](http://code.google.com/p/php-amqplib/)?  Technically there's no need for this to be written as a low-level extension, Amqp is a TCP level protocol, it's possible to implement these in PHP.

Comment: Even if it is not really an answer on the question, I think at this time it is the best solution to use. Many thx!