# phpize command not found on cygwin terminal

Tags: php, cygwin, pear, gearman

when i give phpize on cygwin terminal phpize command not found.Then i tried which phize

it shows which:

> no phpize in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/PC Connectivity Solution:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Lenovo/Bluetooth Software:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php/PEAR)

How should i make  phpize command to work as i needed it for building gearman extension.Should i need to install anything for command to work.my php version is 5.2.4.I checked in php folder no where i cant found the phpize

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711327/how-do-you-compile-a-php-extension-on-windows-with-cygwin-mingw

Comment: please suggest how to install php-dev.As i tried using apt-get install php5-dev on cygwin terminal.But apt-get command not found from cygwin,also tried with apt-cyg install php-dev,it shows package php-dev not found or ambiguos name

Comment: `apt-get` isn't installed on cygwin - its a Debian/Ubuntu application. You can install `apt-cyg` - but whether that has the `php-dev` binary in it - I wouldn't be sure. Everything we have is LAMP