# Relax void * casting in C++

Tags: c++, c, casting, void-pointers

In C, it's not an error to cast pointers to and from `void *`.

A major obstacle in porting to C++ is the need to cast pointers when returning from functions dealing with generic pointers such as `malloc`, and functions declared in my own code such as `void *block_get(Blkno const blkno);`.

My code however is intended to be compiled by C **and** C++ compilers successfully. If I provide explicit casts everywhere for the sake of C++, they must be C-style casts and I may be masking bugs due to casting non-pointer types to and from pointer types from both languages.

My reference error is the following:

```
struct Cpfs *cpfs = calloc(1, sizeof(*cpfs));
```

which in MSVC produces:

> Error  2   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Cpfs *'  e:\src\cpfs\cpfs.c  179

Evidently I can't use `new` or `static_cast` which I'd naturally use if I was no longer using C. **What's the best way to provide maximum type safety surrounding `void *`for each language with minimal verbosity?**

Comment: Why do you need to port to the common subset of C and C++? As you've discovered it severely limits what C (alternatively what C++) you can use. Almost all environments that have C++ available also have C available and also allow you to link C++ and C object files together. I can't see what gain you get by porting to the common subset.

Comment: For *type safety in C* (which is a bit hard), make a function for each struct whose job is to allocate and return a pointer to a new struct. Likewise, make a function for freeing the struct.

Comment: I'd like to know the rationale for trying to write a program that compiles for two different languages. That's typically something left for puzzles.

Comment: BTW, in C++, you should be using `static_cast` to cast to/from `void*`.

Comment: @GMan: the times I've done it have always been `static inline` (or implementation-defined equivalent, in the case of C89) functions in headers relating to a library mostly written in C, but used by both. When things get too hairy trying to work in the intersection, you can give up on that function being `static inline`, and just write it in C.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, `static inline` in header files is bogus premature optimization.

Comment: @R. Fortunately, I've only done it 10% of the time, and I know my code base better than you do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When convert a void pointer to a specific type pointer, which casting symbol is better, static\_cast or reinterpret\_cast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013596/when-convert-a-void-pointer-to-a-specific-type-pointer-which-casting-symbol-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this? (untested, no compiler available, not using macros very often):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define pointer_cast(type, pointer) reinterpret_cast<type>(pointer)
#else
    #define pointer_cast(type, pointer) (type)(pointer)
#endif
```

Comment: Why not just avoid the useless cast entirely when `__cplusplus` is not defined?

Comment: I ended up creating a VOID_CAST macro that cast only when necessary.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest either simply using C style casts, or wrapping the cast in a macro that either expands to nothing (in C), or a `static_cast` in C++.

Comment: A `reinterpret_cast` from `void*` is not the best cast. `static_cast` is sufficient and less likely to silently cast an invalid source to a pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports `decltype()`, you can use some macro magic to avoid having to explicitly repeat the type name (and, thanks to `sizeof`, the element size):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define my_calloc(VAR, COUNT) \
    static_cast<decltype(VAR)>(std::calloc(COUNT, sizeof *VAR))
#else
#define my_calloc(VAR, COUNT) calloc(COUNT, sizeof *VAR)
#endif
```

Example usage:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

struct Cpfs *cpfs = my_calloc(cpfs, 42);
```

The cleaner solution would probably be to just use a C compiler and link the object files, though...

Comment: decltype looks similar to typeof, using a c compiler isn't an option, msvc has no c99 support. c++ compiles it better than a half-assed c compiler

Comment: @Matt: you could use MinGW to compile the C part of your project and still use MSVC for the C++ part (see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib )

Comment: @Matt Joiner: programming to the intersection of C99 and C++ isn't substantially different from just programming C89, it's just more awkward and annoying. You're writing to a half-assed version of C as it is, using a half-assed C compiler isn't any worse, and at least C89's a standard.

Answer (score 1):

make a replacement allocator function that you can define differently for C and C++ builds :- Something like this in a header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
template<typename TypeT>
TypeT* MyAlloc(TypeT** pOut,size_t cb){
  *pOut = static_cast<TypeT*>(malloc(cb)); //aint c++ pretty.
  return *pOut;
}
#else
  extern void* MyAlloc(void** ppv, size_t cb);
#endif
```

Now you have, in c++ builds, a function that can infer the type of thing its dealing with, and in C builds, its a regular function that returns a void*.

The only problem is the need to pass in the pointer to allocate - the c++ compiler wont try to deduce a template parameter based only on the return type of a function afaik. So you could call it agnostically like this :-

```
int *p;
if(MyAlloc(&p,sizeof(int)*n)){
  ...
```

Comment: "//aint c++ pretty." Yeah, when you use `new`.

Comment: `new` is even worse as c++ compilers dont deduce class template parameters from the constructor call. So I had to write something like this the other day: `SomeClass<int(int)>* pWrapper = new SomeOtherClass<int(SomeOtherClass::*)(int)>(this,&SomeOtherClass::method);`

Comment: @Chris: You're using `new` without putting it in a wrapper, your point is moot to me. C++0x has `auto`, and your response is a red-herring anyway.

Comment: Its now a best practice to always bundle calls to new in a wrapper? `auto` only solves half the problem. and new is no more pretty than malloc() especially if the recommended way to avoid the ugliness is to wrap it.

Comment: @Chris: Uh, yeah. That's not even a new idea, it's relatively old. (As in, we've been in a "modern C++" era, where you don't manage your resources manually. Wrap them up (`std::vector`, `shared_ptr`, etc.); it's scope-bound resource management (SBRM) more known as it's ugly name RAII) Any time you have to manually free something, you've done something wrong. Again, this tangent is a red-herring. The code you said was ugly in your post is only ugly because it's not idiomatic C++, replying with some *other* code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is to do explicit casting:

```
struct Cpfs *cpfs = (Cpfs*)calloc(1, sizeof(*cpfs));
```

Here both compilers are satisfied.
Also that remember, that for older compilers malloc may return char*.

hth

Mario