# When convert a void pointer to a specific type pointer, which casting symbol is better, static_cast or reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, casting

In this program I have a `void *` as a parameter and want to cast it to a specific type. But I don't know which "casting symbol" to use.  Both `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` work.  Which one is better? Which one does the Standard C++ recommend?

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
}A, *PA;

int foo(void* a)                // the real type of a is A*
{
    A* pA = static_cast<A*>(a); // or A* pA = reinterpret_cast<A*>(a);?
    return pA->a;
}
```

Here, is

```
A* pA = static_cast<A*>(a);
```

or

```
A* pA = reinterpret_cast<A*>(a);
```

more proper?