# Crosscompiling libmcrypt as a static lib for MSVC

Tags: c++, mingw, static-libraries, cross-compiling, mcrypt

I'm trying to use [libMcrypt](http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/) as a static lib for windows. My code is already using the dll port for it found [here](http://files.edin.dk/php/win32/mcrypt/dev/). 
There does not exists a 'vcproj/solution' for the project so I did not know how to go about to compile it directly using visual studio. ( I was getting abundant errors when I tried to create one and compile)

However, I could cross compile using MingW and get a windows dll which worked fine. I found the instructions [here](https://wiki.physik.fu-berlin.de/linux-minidisc/doku.php?id=compilingwithmingw). I then compiled a static lib for the same giving --enable=static as an option to configure. It created a .a and .la file successfully.

But when I'm trying to use the compile lib, I'm getting the following linker errors in my project

```
libmcrypt.lib(loki97.o) : warning LNK4229: invalid directive '/aligncomm:_prm,5' encountered; ignored
libmcrypt.lib(loki97.o) : warning LNK4229: invalid directive '/aligncomm:_sb2,5' encountered; ignored
libmcrypt.lib(loki97.o) : warning LNK4229: invalid directive '/aligncomm:_sb1,5' encountered; ignored
LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __strdup already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strdup.obj)
     Creating library ..\..\..\bin\myProj.lib and object ..\..\..\bin\myProj.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
libmcrypt.lib(blowfish-compat.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms
myProj.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol arcfour_LTX__is_block_algorithm
myProj.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol arcfour_LTX__mcrypt_algorithm_version
myProj.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol arcfour_LTX__mcrypt_decrypt
myProj.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol arcfour_LTX__mcrypt_encrypt
myProj.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol arcfour_LTX__mcrypt_get_algo_iv_size
myProj.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol arcfour_LTX__mcrypt_get_algorithms_name
myProj.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol arcfour_LTX__mcrypt_get_block_size
```

1. From the 1st two errors, I feel it is a CRT mismatch error. How can
   I give the option to gcc to build static lib without CRT? (I'm not
   sure if I'm thinking correct)
2. Or can I use the .a file, extract obj files and recreate a lib from
   it?
3. Has anyone compile a static lib for libMcrypt on Windows

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you try to search on stackoverflow.com? I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib

Comment: @Sergey: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying (adding the .a file directly to the linker input) but, I'm getting linking errors and also CRT mismatch

Comment: so just change your CRT lib as mentioned "Also, there may occur problems regarding mixed C run-time libraries properties of C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library" - have you tried this?

Comment: @Sergey: Yea, it tried those options too, dint make it work. Currently, I'm getting linking errors for some functions in mcrypt.c which are exposed(probably for a dll build). I've modified their signatures but still it doesn't seem to work..