# gmp library on windows - linking error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol operator <<

Tags: c++

I installed gmp library (version 5.1.2) from source using mingw and msys.

This sample program, taken from Wikipedia:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main()
{
    mpz_class x("7612058254738945");
    mpz_class y("9263591128439081");    

    std::cout << "\n    " << x << "\n*\n    " << y;
    std::cout << "\n--------------------\n" << x * y << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile with mingw:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -O3 -I/c/Libs/GMP/include -L/c/Libs/GMP/lib hello_gmp.cpp -o hellocpp_gmp -lgmpxx -lgmp
```

it compiles and runs.

If I compile with visual studio 2010/2012 gives me the following error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,struct __mpz_struct const *)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@PBU__mpz_struct@@@Z)
```

If I modify the code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main()
{
    mpz_class x("7612058254738945");
    mpz_class y("9263591128439081");
    mpz_class z("0");

    //std::cout << "\n    " << x << "\n*\n    " << y;
    //std::cout << "\n--------------------\n" << x * y << "\n\n";

    z = x * y;
    std::cout << "\n    " << x.get_str() << "\n*\n    " << y.get_str();
    std::cout << "\n--------------------\n" << z.get_str() << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

it compiles and runs.

In the file "gmpxx.h" the << operator is defined as follows:

line 2054 about:

```
/ **************** I / O operators **************** /

// These Should (and will) be provided separately

template <class T, class U>
inline std :: ostream & operator <<
(std :: ostream & o, const __ gmp_expr U> & T, expr)
{
    __gmp_expr <T, T> const & temp (expr);
    return o << temp.__get_mp();
}

template <class T>
inline std :: istream & operator >> (std :: istream & i, __ gmp_expr <t & T, expr)
{
    return i >> expr.__get_mp ();
}
```

line 2880 about:

```
#define __GMP_DEFINE_BINARY_FUNCTION_UI(fun, eval_fun)                 \
                                                                   \
template <class T, class U>                                            \
inline __gmp_expr                                                      \
<T, __gmp_binary_expr<__gmp_expr<T, U>, mp_bitcnt_t, eval_fun> > \
fun(const __gmp_expr<T, U> &expr, mp_bitcnt_t l)                 \
{                                                                      \
    return __gmp_expr<T, __gmp_binary_expr                               \
    <__gmp_expr<T, U>, mp_bitcnt_t, eval_fun> >(expr, l);        \
}
```

line 3080 about:

```
__GMP_DEFINE_BINARY_FUNCTION_UI(operator<<, __gmp_binary_lshift)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `gmpxx` library when linking with VS2012. You probably remembered to include the `gmp` library in your VS library list. Put `gmpxx` there as well and you'll be fine.

Comment: I've included the reference in "Configuration properties/Linker/Input":

odbccp32.lib;libgmpxx.a;libgmp.a;%(AdditionalDependencies)
but the problem remains.

Comment: Next thing I would try is the top rated answer from this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519 ), that is, linking against mingw's libmsvcrt.a. If that doesn't help, I'm out of ideas unfortunately...