# Link ffmpeg lib statically in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg, static-libraries

I'm trying to use ffmpeg in my C++ project on VS2010, and the ffmpeg dev version provides the lib of .h files. I linked these .libs in my projects and the corresponding .dlls are required when running the .exe file. But I want to link the ffmpeg lib statically and running without .dlls.

I tryed to compile the ffmpeg source code on windows with Mingw, only resulting on some .a archive files. How to get ffmpeg static .lib files? And it's a 64bit program so 64bit static lib is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output directory, you have some `*.def` files. You can use these files to get your `*.lib` files. The syntax is:

```
lib /def:avcodec-54.def /out:avcodec-54.lib
```

Use the `lib.exe` of your VS version. Mine is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin`. Check the command line options (it way be useful to  add `/machine:i386`).

Another way to do this: instead of using windows's `cmd` directly to start msys/mingw, first start VS command prompt (you can start it from Start menu). It will set some environment variables. From here, compile FFmpeg with msys/mingw: FFmpeg build will autodetect that VS is present, thus will auto-perform the `lib`call.

**Edit**: Sorry, I skipped the "static" part of the question. Here are some tips for a static build (note that I've never build a static FFmpeg used inside visual studio, so maybe it will not work).
First, of course, FFmpeg must be built with the static options: just to be sure, I use these options, so I have no .def of shared files:

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared [other options]
```

In order to have statically files, you may directly use the .a files (again: I never thried this). Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib).

If it does not work, you can try the visual studio toochain instead of gcc. But be careful: last time I tried this (but a shared dll), FFmpeg decoding was slower when build from msvc than gcc's output. Check [this page](https://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows) for detailed build instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I had compiled ffmpeg in the second way you said, only get *.def files and *.a type of static lib. I tried the lib.exe to transfer *.def to *.lib as the first way you said, and *.lib files are generated. But they seem not to be static lib file according the file size. They have the corresponding same size with those *.lib files which are used with *.dll files.

Comment: I totally missed the "static" point, sorry. I updated my answer with some links, but I never did this myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again, I almost know how to compile ffmpeg in windows, I will try these two ways of getting static *.lib files.