# direct function call from .a libraries without header file

Tags: .a

I want to use the NIST Biometrics Image Software(NBIS) library in Visual Studio.
I use NBIS rel_5.0.0 and Visual Studio 2013. (http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm)

**I compiled the original c code with MinGW, and now I have .a libraries, and .h files.
Can I use the functions from the .a libraries without header files in vc++?**

Is this the best way to do it? (also I put the .a files to Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies)

extern "C" 
{
    int __cdecl function(...

The original NBIS library contains a lot of header and code files, but I can not use them directly in Visual Studio, because there are a lot of header file which are not used by windows, that is why I had to compile it with MinGW.

Comment: You will need the header file for certain declarations etc. Have you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2139061/4281182

Comment: Yes, I have checked, but in my case I use c code.
The weird thing is, this NBIS has a .NET version(http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/bws.cfm), and there they use the .a files without headers. So how does it work exactly?