# Can I use .a library files with visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

I am trying to add an .a library file to my visual studio project. I have included the path from project properties. But it is not recognizing  the classes. I know .lib files work in windows. Is there any way to use .a files with visual studio?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib