# How to use .a files in my Visual C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dvd

This is a more general question, but it refers to libdvdread library. This library is built and distributed as part of the VLC project (www.videolan.org).

I'm wanting to use these open source libraries in my Visual C++ project.

I dove into the archive and have the windows build of my library, libdvdread.a (and .la which I don't really understand) and the header file, so I should be good to go.

How do I use these in my VCC project?

I've googled a bit and found stuff that went the other way, but couldn't find links going this way.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. The library file format for the MSVC compiler is `.lib`. You need to recompile those libraries from scratch at your development environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/ specifies the compiler as minGW. You will be unable to use these libraries with Visual Studio's compiler.

Comment: I was afraid of that.