# What file extensions can a C / C ++ library be?

Tags: c++, c, dll, cmake, static-libraries

I am working on a .png reader and I just got the source code through libpng.com. Now I put all files through CMake and MinGW and now I am unsure what I should get in my library folder for my Reader. Should I just link the libpng.dll or something else? I added a picture. Any Help is appreciate. Thanks!

[image: Folder Image]

Comment: You should show your CMake files too

Comment: Usually, the file extension would be `.a` for a static library, and either `.dll` (on windows) or `.so` (on linux) for a dynamic library. Which one you use is pretty much a matter of personal preference (in some cases there might be technical reasons to prefer one over the other, but usually it doesn't matter).

Comment: Related Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2096519/3987854).

Comment: *CMake* does this automatically for you by specifying `--target INSTALL` to `cmake --build`.