# MSYS2 MinGW64 to build GMP/MPFR on Windows as static library, and link them in MSVC project compiled with CL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gmp, msys2, mpfr

I'm working using Visual Studio 2019. I have a project that requires GMP and MPFR ; as far as I know, there are no recent binaries available for Windows and one has to build his own.

To build GMP/MPFR from source code, I used the `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` installed with the command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` in MSYS2 shell. Then, from the MinGW64 shell, I just used `./configure, make, make install` and ended up with .a libraries, which is, unless I'm wrong, perfectly usable in a VS project.

So now back to my project in Visual Studio, I'm trying to compile it with default compiler CL => it fails with the following errors :

```
Severity    Code    Description                                                                             Project     File                                                Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120     2 unresolved externals                                                                  MyProject   MyProject.exe                                       1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(aors.o)                                    1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(dcpi1_bdiv_q.o)                            1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(dcpi1_bdiv_qr.o)                           1   
Error   LNK2019     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms referenced in function mpn_dcpi1_divappr_q_n    MyProject   libgmp.a(dcpi1_divappr_q.o)                         1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(dcpi1_div_qr.o)                            1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(divexact.o)                                1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(gcd.o)                                     1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(hgcd_reduce.o)                             1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(invertappr.o)                              1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt103-divexact.o)                          1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt31-mul.o)                                1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt55-cmp.o)                                1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt57-cmp_ui.o)                             1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt64-mul.o)                                1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt82-mul.o)                                1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt97-gcd.o)                                1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(lt99-tdiv_qr.o)                            1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(mullo_n.o)                                 1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(mul_n.o)                                   1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(nussbaumer_mul.o)                          1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(sqr.o)                                     1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(toom42_mul.o)                              1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libgmp.a(toom53_mul.o)                              1   
Error   LNK2019     unresolved external symbol __mingw_raise_matherr referenced in function cos             MyProject   libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-cos.o)              1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms                                                 MyProject   libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-mingw_pformat.o)    1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol __mingw_raise_matherr                                        MyProject   libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-sin.o)              1   
Error   LNK2001     unresolved external symbol __mingw_raise_matherr                                        MyProject   libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-sqrt.o)             1
```

I imagine that I need to link my VS project with a static-library from MSYS2 but I canno't figure which one. Following [this topic](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/undefined-reference-with-mingw-vfprintf-td17020.html) I already linked with C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmingwex.a but now I'm quite stuck. Any suggestion?

Comment: You may want to check it see if `vcpkg` supports these libraries and use that to generate binaries that are compatible with Visual Studio.

Comment: Well some people there are saying that you can link with a `.a` library in Visual Studio : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096519/from-mingw-static-library-a-to-visual-studio-static-library-lib.

Comment: Ok `vcpkg` is a good idea, I'm gonna take a look at it.

Comment: I will have to check out your link. I knew there were methods to use `c` compiled mingw static libraries however `c++` compiled libraries don't work.

Comment: So, can GMP be used in Visual Studio with MS compiler? Is there any GMP static library to just throw at linker and just work?

Answer (score 3):

`___chkstk_ms` is defined in libgcc (`...\msys64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\10.1.0\libgcc.a`).

`__mingw_raise_matherr` is defined in libmingw32 (`...\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmingw32.a`).

I don't know if this will help you get a working executable though. :)  C++ is out of the question, but it seems you haven't bumped into that particular issue so far.

You can find these symbols using simple substring search and confirm using `nm` (`T` stands for a defined symbol, `U` for an undefined one).  You can also call GCC with verbosity turned up to see the exact linker command behind the scenes, or call `gcc -dumpspecs` to read exactly when is what linked in.